# private static и private final static - зачем?

Tags: java

В каких случаях следует помечать переменные таким образом? Какой толк от `static`, если он помечен как `private`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Посмотрите данные по шаблону проектирования [singleton](/questions/tagged/singleton).

`private static` гарантирует единственность экземпляра объекта с такими свойствами в потоке, где задействован класс.

`private static final` гарантирует, что этот экземпляр не подменится на что-то другое.

Удобно при работе с базами данных или каким-то ресурсом, не склонным к разделению.

Answer (score 9):

> Какой толк от static, если он помечен как private?

Необходимо, если переменную нужно использовать в статических методах

```
public class CarFactoryFacade {

   private static CarFactory audiFactory = new AudiCarFactory();
   private CarFactory bmwFactory = new BMWCarFactory();

   public static Car createAudi() {
       return audiFactory.createCar();
   }

   public static Car createBMW() {
       return bmwFactory.createCar(); <-- ошибка
   }
```

> private final static - зачем?

Final нужно использовать, если ссылка будет инициализироваться один раз и не должна быть заменена. В большинстве случаев `static` переменные именно так и используются.

Если `static` переменная изменяется в ходе программы, скорее всего есть какие то проблемы с дизайном (`static` - отсутствие экземпляра объекта, в каком то смысле отсутствие состояния, изменение ссылки - смена состояние -> противоречие).

Answer (score 1):

Модификаторы доступа `static final` следует применять, когда есть необходимость явно указать на то, что переменную не следует или запрещено изменять, то есть модификаторы `static final` превращают переменную в константу.

---

В свою очередь переменные помеченные модификатором `static` являются обычными переменными с тем лишь различием, что их экземпляр (в единственном числе) хранится не с экземпляром каждого создаваемого объекта (области памяти где хранятся переменные экземпляра), а в объекте который описывает ваш класс при этом на каждой JVM такой объект существует в единственном экземпляре. С переменными объявленными как `static` можно делать все то же что и с обычными переменными при этом для доступа к таким переменным ненужно (но можно получить доступ и через переменную экземпляра) создавать экземпляр класса (конечно если переменная имеет модификатор доступа `public`), например, создадим класс содержащий статическую переменную:

```
public class MyClass{
    public static int classVariable = 10;
}
```

Получение подступа к статической переменной:

```
MyClass.classVariable;
```

Присваиваем новое значение статической переменной:

```
MyClass.classVariable = 100;
```

Такие переменные следует применять, когда есть необходимость иметь одну переменную на все экземпляры классов или если необходимо использовать переменную в статическом методе (переменные экземпляра в таком методе недоступны так как экземпляров класса может вообще не существовать на момент вызова статического метода).

При использовании модификатора private свойства переменной и «константы» не изменяются, изменяется лишь доступность переменной/константы.