# Преимущества static переменной в сравнении с обычной

Tags: java

Никак не могу понять, зачем они есть. В книгах пишут, что инициализация у них в первую очередь. Убрать магические числа? Так это можно сделать и обычной переменной. Да, удобно обращаться (SomeClass.var). Глобальная область видимости? Так у обычной переменной можно поменять модификатор доступа на public.

Comment: преимущества молотка по сравнению с отверткой (и наоборот)

Comment: Преймуществ нет. Static - это еще один инструмент который при грамотном использовании решает ряд задач.

Comment: буду благодарен. если привидете пример таких задач. sorry

Comment: @Igor успел)))) Реализация паттерна singleton к примеру

Comment: `static` позволит вам хранить переменную, не имея ни одного объекта класса. Как пример если вам нужно ограничить число создаваемых объектов класса.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525115/private-static-%d0%b8-private-final-static-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc/525120#525120

Answer (score 5):

Положим у вас есть класс DbHelper. Он имеет конструктор, принимающий имя БД, к которой он должен подключиться. Положим, что таких БД у вас всего две - вы создаёте в классе DbHelper 2 публичные статические переменные и выбираете одну из них при создании объекта вашего DbHelper для подключения к к-л конкретной БД. Выглядеть это будет в итоге как-то так:

```
DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(DbHelper.TABLE_CATS);
```

Если бы статических переменных не существовало, то вы не смогли бы так создавать экземпляр этого класса. Вам бы пришлось создавать лишние переменные в каждом классе, где вы подключаетесь к БД.

---

Есть и много других примеров пользования статических переменных, но говорить о их преимуществах перед обычными переменными некорректно, т.к. это отдельный инструмент для отдельных задач.