# Возвращаемые значения c модификатором final в Java

Tags: java

В статье по Java 8 увидел пример определения того, есть ли в коллекции данный элемент:

```
private static final boolean haveHello() {
        return LONG_WELCOME.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.equals("Hello"));
    }
```

Для чего возвращаемое значение определено как `final`? Что полезного это дает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static final методы используются для того, чтобы быть результат вычислений был в единственном экземпляре для всего приложения, а сам метод нельзя было бы переопределить.

Вот [источник](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) и [вот](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)

Также, вам может понравиться вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525276/216510) этот ответ про переменные.